# Using MPVolumeView with MPMoviePlayerController in Swift

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, volume, mpvolumeview

I'm trying to use the MPMoviePlayerController to play an audio stream. It is actually working and it is quite pleasing. However, I would like users to be able to control the volume with a slider. I've searched a lot, and most people are using AVPlayer with MPVolumeView, but I couldn't figure out how to use a stream with that.

Nonetheless, is there a way for me to use the code and setup I have now, but implement a UISlider to control volume?

Here is a screenshot of what I have. The play/pause button works, users can call by tapping the #, visit the website by tapping the link. I would like to be able to use the slider displayed to control device volume. https://41.media.tumblr.com/675b910c01821692ccd952ecd847a55a/tumblr_nlkztlnfIq1r4x08fo1_1280.png

Thanks.

```
var stream: MPMoviePlayerController!

@IBOutlet weak var requestText: UILabel! = UILabel()
@IBOutlet weak var callNumber: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var valume: UISlider!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    playButton.hidden = true
    streamPlayer()




}

func streamPlayer() {

    stream = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: NSURL(string: "http://peace.str3am.com:6910/")!)

    stream.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    stream.view.sizeToFit()

    stream.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming

    self.view.addSubview(stream.view)

    stream.fullscreen = false
    stream.prepareToPlay()
    stream.play()

    stream.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

}


@IBAction func pausePressed(sender: UIButton) {
    stream.stop()
    pauseButton.hidden = true
    playButton.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func playPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    stream.play()
    pauseButton.hidden = false
    playButton.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func phoneRequest(sender: UIButton) {
    pauseButton.hidden = true
    playButton.hidden = false
    stream.stop()
    requestText.text = "Calling..."
    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(6072741059)"){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}




@IBAction func visitWeb(sender: UIButton) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://vicradio.org/"){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
}

@IBAction func sliderVal(sender: UISlider) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a UIView object and change the class to MPVolumeView.